# Copying dataframe data effectively

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe:

```
dataframe = pd.DataFrame()
dataframe['column'] = [10,20,30,40]
```

I want to effectively duplicate each element 3 times so it becomes the equivalent of:

```
dataframe['column'] = [10,10,10,20,20,20,30,30,30,40,40,40]
```

I need a solution that will work for a df of any size.I also need the index to stay 1,2,3,4 etc..

Comment: `dataframe['column'] = np.repeat(dataframe.column, 3)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
magic_list = [10,20,30,40]
dataframe['column'] = [x for y in [[a for i in range(3)] for a in magic_list] for x in y]
```